# How to make get request to aws Api using React js

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have make request to aws api with get method using React js But it shows error :-
 "Access to fetch at 'https://blahblah.com/dev/getControllist' from origin 'http://test.com:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."
But If I hit same api direct to browser or using postman it returns json successfully. Please help me if anyone knows. 
My code is:-

```
var uri = "blahblah.com/dev/getControllist";
    let h = new Headers({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,x-access-token"

        });       


    let request = new Request(uri,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: h,
            cors:true
        });

    fetch(request)
        .then((result) => {
            // Get the result
            // If we want text, call result.text()              

            return result.json();

        }).then((jsonResult) => {
            // Do something with the result
            console.log(jsonResult);
            this.setState({
                items: jsonResult
            });
```

Comment: You need your server to be configured to serve proper CORS headers: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I followed all the steps in the https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html but i am getting same error in console @JoeClay

Comment: Try removing those headers from your request - they're meant to be in the response, not the request.

Comment: Thank you so much now it is working @JoeClay :)